# Hexdump macro (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, macros, hexdump

I have a working hexdump function but it seems to be overkill for printing a single variable. So I am trying to make a macro for it. So far this works almost perfectly:

```
#define PRINT_FMT2(val,des,fmt) printf(#des" = "fmt": "SRC_STRN,val)
// SRC_STRN is a macro that evals to string literal containing file and line# 

#include <stdint.h>
#define PRINT_HEX(x) PRINT_FMT2((*((uint32_t*)(&(x)))),x,"%x") 
// the lack of parens around 2nd arg to PRINT_FMT2 is okay cause it gets #'d
```

The only issue with this is that I cannot use it with the return value of a function. I get the error `lvalue required as unary '&' operand`. I think this means that I can't use this method of casting ptr to uint-ptr. Is there another efficient way to do this?

**Edit**: I'd like to mention that what most people glossed over is that I wanted to see my value bit-preserved and converted to an unsigned int hexadecimal format. Note that you may use my macro with an l-value `float` and it spits out the correct big-endian representation. Most regular hex-dump routines will print out the bits as it is written in memory, which clearly is dependent on endianness. My bad for not being clear about what I meant.

Anyway, I ended up writing a set of overloaded functions which can be used with an r-value. In the end I only really just wanted to use it on 32-bit floats.

```
inline uint32_t tohex(float f) { 
  uint32_t* u = (uint32_t *)&f; return *u; 
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. A function is a much better choice than a macro. It does not buy you anything to use a macro and your abusing what the macros is designed for (its not a function replacement).

Comment: Functions **are** the efficient way to do it. You're wasting time and needlessly complicating your code.

Comment: You can get it to work by declaring a variable for holding the value of `x` inside the macro, but just using a function is probably better.

Comment: **Please** don't do this, you are just complicating your code for no good reason.

Comment: There is no reason to have `fcpy` in your function. Just take the address of `f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Macros should be used sparingly because they are highly bug prone, and difficult to debug.

In this case, you won't get any performance gain from using a macro, because a short function like this is probably going to get inlined.

You will get a readability gain by using a function.  There are also many language features you get from functions, such as overloading, type safety, and potential to pass it as a function pointer.  You may not need them now, but you might in the future.

It will also be easier to write.

All in all, a function is a much much better choice in this case.

Plus there are already functions built into the language to do what you're trying to do, both in C++, and in C (if you need the speed).

**Edit**

If you really want to figure out how to make it a macro, and want to know why this doesn't work, see dappawit's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is saying you cannot take the address of the return value because it is not an L-value.  To take the address, you need an object that actually has an address.  Such objects can appear on the left size of an assignment, hence the term L-value.

A function call cannot appear to the left of an assignment--the return value is *not* an L-value.  This is why you get the error.  In C, it makes no sense to take the address of the return value.  (In C++, you can return references.  In that case, you *can* take the address of the return value.  However, other returned values have the same restrictions as in C--they are not L-values.)

Comment: I already understand all of this but it's really great that you went over it again and I'm sure it will be helpful for future readers of this question. +1. If nobody posts an answer soon that says "Don't use a macro for this!" I will accept this.

Comment: I appreciate that.  But, don't accept it unless you think it's the right answer.  In my opinion, it's perfectly okay not to accept any answer, on occasion.

Comment: And for the record, the other commenters are correct in my opinion--this is not a good use for macros.